# JavaFX uneditable combobox - strange reaction on DELETE keystroke

Tags: javafx, combobox

**Preamble**

I have uneditable combobox (user can select from list, but can't type). I suppose, when user have focus on it and press DELETE, it's selection must be cleared? It seems that it is (screenshot was made when I selected some value and then pressed DELETE):
[selectionModel is null - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxayi.png)

**Problem**

But UI control still shows old value, it wasn't cleared. Also ValueChanged listener wasn't triggered.

**How to cause**

Create ComboBox and fill it with some values. Select any value. You already have selection on it, but it's not enough - now DELETE pressing won't even clear selectionModel. The same with selecting by TAB. Select it with double click (expand and collapse) and then press DELETE. Now selectionModel must be cleared, but UI still show your value.

Another thing: if you closed ComboBox, pressing DELETE will trigger ValueChanged listener. Pressing DELETE on expanded ComboBox won't trigger it, but nevertheless value will become null.

Did anybody face with this? Any ideas to make it work naturally i.e. clear selectionModel and update UI?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) lists the differences between the `valueProperty` and the selection model's `itemProperty`. It would be helpful if you posted a [MCVE], instead of expecting people to write code themselves.

Comment: @James_D, I tried itemProperty instead of valueProperty, but nothing changed. Thanks for advice about MCVE, I'll keep it in mind next time, but now I'm not sure what to post here :) Problem isn't in code but in behaviour.

Comment: My point was that you are asking people to help *you*. It's easier for them to help if they can see the actual problem. I know the problem is not specifically with your code - but for us to actually see the problem we have to take the time to write the code. It's not difficult, but why would I spend time doing something to help you out when you could do it yourself? If you make it easier for people to help you, you're more likely to get help. An example will make it clearer what the issue is as well.

Comment: @James_D, so I resolved problem while making minimal example :) Thx for responsiveness.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the problem was not exactly where I thought. "Delete" button did nothing in any case, `ComboBox` was cleared because it's items list was refreshed every time when it was expanded -> old items were deleted including selected. Problem was the same - UI wasn't updated. So I resolved this by adding `ComboBox.getEditor().clear()` before refreshing it's items list in `onShowing` event.